# What does it mean for summation to be "pointwise"?

Tags: real-analysis

> let $\{u\}$ be a sequence of nonnegative measurable functions on E. If $f=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} u_n$ pointiwse a.e. on E, then $\int_E f = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \int_E u_n$.

I know what it means for convergence to be pointwise, but I don't understand how summation can be "pointwise".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account that it’s 'a.e.', i.e., almost everywhere, it means that for almost all $x\in E$, $f(x)=\sum_{n\ge 1}u_n(x)$. Since you understand *pointwise* in the context of sequences, remember that the statement that $f=\sum_{n\ge 1}u_n$ means that the sequence of partial sums converges to $f$. Let $f_m=\sum_{n=1}^mu_n$, the $m$-th partial sum. Then the assertion is that $\langle f_m:m\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ converges pointwise to $f$ almost everywhere: for almost all $x\in E$, $\lim_{m\to\infty}f_m(x)=f(x)$.

Comment: So if it was everywhere instead of "a.e.", then we would say $f(x)=\sum_{n\geq1}u_n(x)$ uniformly?

Comment: @Artus: No, the convergence needn’t be uniform; that’s a stronger condition.

Comment: @Artus: There's a limit implicit in the sum. "Pointwise" and "uniform" refer to how you take the limit.